# How to reliably run custom code when related (ForeignKey) objects change

Tags: django

In a simple ForeignKey relation, I want to run specific code when one of the related object is modified.

Here a schematic code :

```
class Car(models.Model):
  pass

class Wheel(models.Model):
  car = models.ForeignKey('Car',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='wheels', 
        null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    my_custom_code()
```

According to [django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add), the reverse related manager method `.add` perform the save in database using `update()` instead of `save()` by default. (idem for .remove, etc...)
So in the below code, the my_custom_code isn't called when using `.add`:

```
car = Car.objects.create()
wheel = Wheel.objects.create()  # ok my_custom_code called here

car.wheels.add(wheel)  # not called here because django use "update mechanism" which do not use save method
```

We need to indicate `bulk=False` to add method in order to force using `save` method.

```
car.wheels.add(wheel, bulk=False) # ok my_custom_code called here
```

This is a problem for me as it is important that the my_custom_code is called when any of the related objects is modified. If someone forgot to indicate bulk=False, it will generate inconsistent data.

There is a signal for this case ? (like m2m_changed signal)
There is a way to force bulk=False for all methods of a ForeignKey relation ?

Thanks for your help.

Why I need this ? My X problem is to store a computed result depending of the related elements in the parent record. (and I need this value always be up to date)
My initial idea was to do computation every time a related model is modified by overriding save.

Comment: You should ask yourself whether you really need to store a computed result. If it can be computed, why do you want to store it? It's always a bad idea to save computed results, exactly because of these synchronisation problems.

Comment: Because it will be much more easier and efficient to query records based on the computation. (The query needed to do a database query based one the computation require two subqueries)

Comment: A lot of computations can be performed directly and very efficiently in a query, using annotations, aggregations, subqueries, F(), and query functions. So allow me to doubt the efficiency issue (unless you've measured the actual "inefficiency"). But the reason I'm saying this is that I don't believe there's a quick solution to your problem, apart from heavily modifying/subclassing the django code to create your own ForeignKey subclass with its own related manager subclass etc...